# IDownloaderClient onServiceConnected Not Being Called

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files, serviceconnection

I'm trying to get my app to download expansion files when it starts up. I followed the [guide from Android](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) and for a while it would start to download, then stop at 98% telling me that it couldn't verify the file, but the file was actually there. Today, I haven't changed any code, and it's not even trying to download. I've put breakpoints all over the class and it never gets to the `onServiceConnected` method that comes from `IDownloaderClient`.

At the end of **onCreate** I have

```
initializeDownloadUI();

if (!expansionFilesDelivered()) {
    try {
        final Intent launchIntent = MainActivity.this.getIntent();
        final Intent intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this.getClass());

        intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setAction(launchIntent.getAction());

        if (launchIntent.getCategories() != null) {
            for (String category : launchIntent.getCategories())
                intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.addCategory(category);
        }

        // Build PendingIntent used to open this activity from Notification.
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Request to start the download.
        final int startResult = DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(this, pendingIntent, DownloaderServiceHelper.class);

        if (startResult != DownloaderClientMarshaller.NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED) {
            initializeDownloadUI();
            return;
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException exc) {
        Log.wtf("MainActivity", "Cannot find own package.");
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
} else validateXAPKZipFiles();
```

And my **initializeDownloadUI()** is

```
mDownloaderClientStub = DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub(this, DownloaderService.class);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

mPB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
mStatusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusText);
mProgressFraction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressAsFraction);
mProgressPercent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressAsPercentage);
mAverageSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressAverageSpeed);
mTimeRemaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressTimeRemaining);
mDashboard = findViewById(R.id.downloaderDashboard);
mCellMessage = findViewById(R.id.approveCellular);
mPauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
mWiFiSettingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wifiSettingsButton);

mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(this);
mWiFiSettingButton.setOnClickListener(this);
(findViewById(R.id.resumeOverCellular)).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Also, my **onResume** is

```
if (null != mDownloaderClientStub) {
    mDownloaderClientStub.connect(this);
}

super.onResume();
```

It steps through the onCreate as expected, but for some reason it doesn't connect the service. Like I said, this was working a few days ago and I didn't change anything, but now it doesn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Service class name is `DownloaderServiceHelper`
So you need to change the code in `initializeDownloadUi` method

from

`mDownloaderClientStub = DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub(this, DownloaderService.class);`

to

`mDownloaderClientStub = DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub(this, DownloaderServiceHelper.class);`